# Is there a separate index for Curse of Strahd?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, curse-of-strahd

I have Curse of Strahd, but it doesn't contain an index like the PHB or DMG do.  I understand it's a campaign, but an index would be so handy for finding areas, NPCs, and terms.

I've found enhanced indexes of other WotC books created by fans, so I know that one *could* exist, but I've found nothing on Curse of Strahd so far.

Does an official or fan index for Curse of Strahd exist?

Comment: Is there a reason as to why the *table of contents* isn't sufficient for the task? Or put differently, what more precise information are you wanting detailed in which the table of contents doesn't help?

Comment: Yes, there is.  For example, an index could reference all the pages NPC Ireena or Rahadin is mentioned.  The table of contents doesn't provide that info.

Comment: Voting to leave open.  OP wants a specific item, an index for a module, and is asking whether one exists.  This is _not_ a shopping question that has multiple open-ended opinion answers and begs clarifying details to answer.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/180169/Curse-of-Strahd-DMs-Kit--Screen) 3PP material produced by [these people](http://www.neuronphaser.com/) includes an NPC index, but also a bunch of other stuff along the lines of indices and concordances of information.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I did find that, but wasn't what I was looking for.  I did start an index and realized what a tremendous undertaking it would be.  Not sure how to post what I put together thus far though (assuming anyone is interested or would like to add/collaborate)

Comment: Can you explain how that product fails to meet your needs?  Doing so in your question will help you get better answers.  Right now, your only criterion is 'lists NPC references by page number' and that's in a comment (which should also be edited it)

Comment: I wouldn't say the product 'fails', just that an index would be handy.  Reviewing my original question, I referred to 'finding areas, NPCs, and terms.', not just NPCs.  The NPC's was just an example when replying to someone asking for clarification.